# Can AWS S3 Multipart Upload use signature V2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, digital-signature

According to [the AWS S3 documentation for Multipart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadInitiate.html) (emphasis added):

> For request signing, multipart upload is just a series of regular requests—you initiate a multipart upload, you send one or more requests to upload parts, and then you complete the multipart upload. You sign each request individually. There is nothing special about signing multipart upload requests. ***For more information about signing, see Authenticating Requests (AWS Signature Version 4)***.

Does that mean that Multipart Upload *requires* signature V4? Or can you also use signature V2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the region:

> Amazon S3 supports Signature Version 4, a protocol for authenticating
>   inbound API requests to AWS services, in all AWS regions. At this
>   time, AWS regions created before January 30, 2014 will continue to
>   support the previous protocol, Signature Version 2. Any new regions
>   after January 30, 2014 will support only Signature Version 4 and
>   therefore all requests to those regions must be made with Signature
>   Version 4. For more information about AWS Signature Version 2, see
>   [Signing and Authenticating REST Requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) in the *Amazon Simple Storage*
>   *Service Developer Guide*.